# Springboot callable async operation with liberty executor configuration

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

We have springboot microservice running on liberty server. We have liberty configured with executor threads core and max size, in parallel can we also have callable implementation on the service to make a maximum utilisation of machine? or will it have counter effect?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instruct Spring to use Liberty's default managed executor (which runs tasks on the Liberty thread pool) by supplying a [DefaultManagedTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/DefaultManagedTaskExecutor.html) to the Spring [AsyncSupportConfigurer.setTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/AsyncSupportConfigurer.html#setTaskExecutor-org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor-) method.

This will cause Spring to look up java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService which is available in Liberty if you enable the `concurrent-1.0` feature.

This page has an example of setting the task executor in Spring, except it uses a custom thread pool, and you would replace that with DefaultManagedTaskExecutor:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/async-rest-controller-callable/

Comment: Thank you, one more followup question to understand more, If I don't configure spring with any async task executor and only configure liberty executor with core and max, would application spawn thread based on liberty configuration?

Comment: That depends on what default is used by Spring in the absence of any specified TaskExecutor, which from this Spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html appears to be that SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is used. SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor includes a warning that it "does not reuse threads". That means no Liberty executor threads or config are used and no thread pooling at all for that matter.